# How to extract integer from Java Regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

Pardon my novelty in java, I have the following string ( Below ), I am trying to clean it and extract only the `integer digits`. What would be the correct java regex to use to achieve my goal:

Original String : `uint32_t Count "77 (0x0000004D)"`

Desired Output: `77`

I have tried reading Java docs on regex but I only got more confused. I guess EE engineers are not cut for this fancy coding tricks :D

Comment: Could you give some more examples to point out a pattern ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

Answer (score 0):

You could exploit `"\\b"` which is a word boundary:

```
String regex = "\\b\\d+\\b";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher("uint32_t Count \"77 (0x0000004D)\"");
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group()); //output 77
```

`"\\d+"` finds a substring of digits, and surrounding it with `"\\b"` ensures that it is not embedded in another word/symbol.

Answer (score 0):

more examples to get a pattern helps but with what you have given i can think of a simple regex that matches the group with the given pattern and then you strip out the quote and get your integer.

```
(["](\d{1,}))
```

I would suggest you play around regex more over [here](http://regexr.com/) so you learn as you practice